# Magento 2: Checkout order summary show custom product attribute failed to load component issue

Tags: magento2, checkout, product-attribute, knockoutjs

I'm trying to show custom product attribute in checkout order summary section.
I have achieved this by override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js`
and `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html` files in my custom module and also created plugin
for `getconfig()` method to store custom attribute in totalsData.

My question is:

1] If i override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js` file using
`app/code/Test/Checkoutsummary/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` file then custom attribute shows in order summary but product thumbnail image not showing and in console js error shows as below:

[image]

app/code/Test/Checkoutsummary/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details': 'Test_Checkoutsummary/js/view/summary/item/details'
        }
    }
};
```

2] If i override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js` file using
`app/code/Test/Checkoutsummary/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` layout file instead of `requirejs-config.js` file then custom attribute shows as well as all section looks proper and
also no error found in console.

app/code/Test/Checkoutsummary/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"
                                                                  xsi:type="string">Test_Checkoutsummary/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

So i'm not figure out why it shows console error when override `summary/item/details.js` file
using `requirejs-config.js` file.
Having anybody faced this type of issue? Any help should be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found issue. I'm trying to override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js`
file using requirejs-config.js file.

Here because of requirejs mapping, all files which have 
`Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details` path replaced with `Test_Checkoutsummary/js/view/summary/item/details`
path and if we look into our custom module's `view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item` path then there is only `details.js`
file exist but another files like thumbnail.js,message.js,subtotal.js not there so in console it shows 404 not found error.

For resolve this problem we have to add thumbnail.js,message.js,subtotal.js file's path in requirejs-config.js
mapping like following:-

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details': 'Marvel_Checkoutsummary/js/view/summary/item/details',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail': 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/message': 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/message',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/subtotal': 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/subtotal'                  
        }
    }
};
```